# Getting rid of lists of empty strings

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with lists of empty string:

```
df.Answers.head()
0    ['In next 3 months', 'In next 6 months', 'In n...
1    ["Doctor's availability in hotel", 'Ventilator...
2    ['Buffet breakfast with social distancing', 'B...
3    ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ...
4                                                 ['']
```

I'd like to get rid of them. So I tried:

```
def remove_empty_arrays(answers):
...     if answers in [[''], ["'"], []]:
...         print("Got an empty bracket")
...         return None
... df.Answers.map(remove_empty_arrays)
```

But it never works, I never have any message printed back confirming a match.

## Update

- I tried the answer of Andrej Kesly but it seems to burst the strings which wern't empty:

```
    df.Answers.apply(lambda x: [v for v in x if v not in ('', '"')])
    0       [[, ', I, n,  , n, e, x, t,  , 3,  , m, o, n, ...
    1       [[, D, o, c, t, o, r, ', s,  , a, v, a, i, l, ...
    2       [[, ', B, u, f, f, e, t,  , b, r, e, a, k, f, ...
    3       [[, ', 1, ', ,,  , ', 2, ', ,,  , ', 3, ', ,, ...
    4                                            [[, ', ', ]]
```

- I also tried the answer of Mahya Mk but it got rid of everything:

```
    def remove_empty_arrays(answers):
    ...     if answers in [["''"],['""']]:
    ...         print("Got an empty bracket")
    ...         return None
    ... df.Answers = df.Answers.map(remove_empty_arrays)    
    df.Answers.head()
    0    None
    1    None
    2    None
    3    None
    4    None
    Name: Answers, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to filter list items:

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Answers':[ ['"', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', ''], []]})

        Answers
0  [", a, b, c]
1      [d, e, ]
2            []
```

---

Then:

```
df.Answers = df.Answers.apply(lambda x: [v for v in x if v not in ('', '"')])    
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     Answers
0  [a, b, c]
1     [d, e]
2         []
```

---

EDIT: If values is just strings, **not** list of strings, you can do something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from ast import literal_eval


df = pd.DataFrame({'Answers':[ '''['"', 'a', 'b', 'c']''', '''['d', 'e', '']''', '''[]''']})

df.Answers = df.Answers.apply(lambda x: [v for v in literal_eval(x) if v not in ('', '"')])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     Answers
0  [a, b, c]
1     [d, e]
2         []
```

Note: It's better to resolve this issue at the source - so don't put strings inside the dataframe, but parse them before (or don't save them as strings but list of strings).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried it but it seems to burst the strings which aren't empty

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica If I look at your edit, does it mean that `['In next 3 months', 'In next 6 months', 'In n...` is one **string**, not list of strings? Like `s = "['In next 3 months', 'In next 6 months']"`?

Comment: You're damn right. I didn't noticed when doing the df.Answers.head() but with df.Answers[0] I have something like that indeed

Answer (score 0):

I think Andrej's answer is right. but you should add this string in your list:
" '' ",' "" '
How can I find it?
I simulate your dataframe and I saw that your empty list is not actually empty because of your outputs.

This is my try:
First, I create a sample DataFrame like this:

`data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack','mah','mahy','mahya','mahyam','mahyamk'], 'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18,20,21,23,23,24],'Answer':[ ['In next 3 months', 'In next 6 months', 'In month'],["Doctor's availability in hotel", 'Ventilator'],['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'],["''"],["''"],["''"],["''"],["''"],["''"]]}`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.Answer.head()
```

I got this output:

```
0    [In next 3 months, In next 6 months, In month]
1      [Doctor's availability in hotel, Ventilator]
2                       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
3                                              ['']
4                                              ['']
5                                              ['']
6                                              ['']
7                                              ['']
8                                              ['']
Name: Answer, dtype: object>
```

So, I remark them this way:

```
for item in df.Answer:
    #print(item)
    if item in [["''"],['""']]:
      print("Got an empty bracket")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it gets rid of everything :/ I've updated my question with my attempt